# RegExp to emails started with something

Tags: regex, virtual, alias, postfix-mta

I want to create a mask in Postfix to send to someone all e-mails started with a word, and including the domain name in the rule. My problem is not how to do this in Postfix (I know). My problem is create the RegExp to do what I want :(

In general:

```
promo*@example.com -> mybox@example.com
```

So, if someone sends an email to:

```
promotion@example.com
promoter@example.com
promospecial@example.com
```

or anything started with "promo", a specific mail with receive all of them. But needs to have the domain, because this needs to work to example.com but not to example.org.

I tried several things like /(^promo.*)/+@example.com but nothing works. I really have problem with RegExp.

Comment: Isn't there a utility to parse the domain out of an email address? I mean, the spec suggests a monster regex that is over 20k when parsed and formatted. (I can post the regex it if you like)

Comment: No, Postfix checks agains the regexp. Ben Craig solved the problem.

Comment: Dunno, a simple regex to do Email parsing _is_ a 20k regular expression. That's the simple one. I mean I could optimize it down to 5k (maybe less) or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regexp, things within () are searched for exactly, and .* is any number of any chars.

So `/(promo).*(@example.com)/` is what I believe you're looking for.

Try using http://www.regexr.com/ in the future to make your regexp if you need regexp help.

Answer (score 1):

this should work in postfix as it seems to support lookaheads:

Search: `promo[^@\s]*?(?=@example\.com)`

Replace: `mybox`

**Explain Regex**

```
promo                    # 'promo'
[^@\s]*?                 # any character except: '@', whitespace (\n,
                         # \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                         # (matching the least amount possible))
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  @example               #   '@example'
  \.                     #   '.'
  com                    #   'com'
)                        # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: @Arvy Hey Arvy, did this help with your question? Or are you still wrestling with it? Did this solve your problem? Btw I notice you haven't yet accepted an answer on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an answer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Comment: Yes, works too, but Ben's is simplier and worked. Sorry about the "accept", I'm new here, I didnt know about this. Done. See ya.